# How to group by using enums in LINQ c# and find max value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

```
public enum Department{ Accounts, Technology, Architecture, MBA };
public class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ExamScores;
    public Department dep;
}
```

I have a list of students. How should I display students who got top marks from each departments using LINQ.
I've tried but couldn't succeed.Please suggest.

Comment: Please show us your attempts. Also it would help to see inputs and desired outputs. And finally  - is it EF query (or some other ORM) or "plain" LINQ-to-objects you are interested in.

Comment: students .GroupBy(s => s.dep).Select(g => ( g.Key, g.Select(v => v.ExamScores).Max() ) );

Answer (score 2):

As commented it's a good idea to always include what you have tried. Both because it shows you've made an effort and it's possible for someone to help pointing out where you went wrong, which you'll learn more from.

That being said, you can solve this problem by grouping in two steps:

1. Group by `dep`
2. Then by `ExamScores`

And lastly order the results to get those with the highest scores:

```
// "one"-liner:
var results = students.GroupBy(s => s.dep)
    .Select(depGroup => depGroup.GroupBy(s => s.ExamScores)
        .OrderByDescending(scoreGroup => scoreGroup.Key) // Key is the ExamScores
        .First()); // First = Get the first group, which has the highest score
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rX2iGe) for an example.

```
// Example output:
// ID  dep           ExamScores
// 3   Accounts      9
// 7   Accounts      9
// 4   Technology    8
// 6   Architecture  6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group the students by department, then find all the students in each group who have a score that matches the highest score for that department:

```
var departmentStudents = students.GroupBy(s => s.dep);

foreach (var department in departmentStudents)
{
    var highScore = department.Max(ds => ds.ExamScores);

    var bestStudents = department
        .Where(student => student.ExamScores == highScore)
        .Select(student => $"{student.FirstName} {student.LastName}");

    Console.WriteLine($"Sudents with best score in the {department.Key} Dept.:");
    Console.WriteLine($" - {string.Join("\r\n - ", bestStudents)}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following list of students:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student> {
                new Student("x", "y", 1, 10, Department.Accounts),
                new Student("p", "q", 2,20, Department.Accounts),
                new Student("p2", "q2", 2, 20, Department.Accounts),
                new Student("a", "b", 3, 30, Department.Technology),
                new Student("m", "n", 4, 40, Department.Technology),
                new Student("m2", "n2", 4, 40, Department.Technology),
            };
```

Now you can group by departments and find the students with highest marks by following approach:

```
var groupsByDept = students.GroupBy(a => (a.dep.ToString()));
List<Student> studentsByHighestMarksAndDeptList = groupsByDept.SelectMany(a => a.Where(b => b.ExamScores == a.Max(c => c.ExamScores))).ToList();
```

This will give the following result:
[image]